# Make launchd jobs depend on other launchd jobs

Tags: macos, launchd

I need to write a launchd job that depends on another launchd job to start.

The `KeepAlive/OtherJobActive` directive has been removed since macOS 10.10.

What can I use on macOS 10.10+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`launchd` doesn't manage job dependencies, you need to manage this in your own code, either be checking whether the functionality provided by the first job is actually available or by creating signal files or other markers.